# How to connect a C# application to a Google CLoud SQL database

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am hosting a SQL Server 2022 Express database in Google Cloud which I want to access from a C# application.

I had no problem connecting using a Python application using this code:

```
from google.cloud.sql.connector import Connector, IPTypes
import sqlalchemy
import os

# initialize Connector object
connector = Connector()

# function to return the database connection object
def getconn():
    conn = connector.connect(
        f"data-warehous-511371:europe-west3:test-sql",
        "pytds",
        user="sqlserver",
        password=f'{open(os.path.join("pw", "pw.txt"), "r").read().strip()}',
        db="mytestdb",
        ip_type=IPTypes.PUBLIC,
    )
    return conn

# create connection pool with 'creator' argument to our connection object function
pool = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
    f"mssql+pytds://",
    creator=getconn,
)

with pool.connect() as db_conn:
    results = db_conn.execute(sqlalchemy.text("SELECT * FROM dbo.testtable")).fetchall()

print(results)
```

Additionally I had to set my service account json file using this command in the terminal:

```
set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=C:\path\to\my\serviceAcc.json
```

Now I want to do the same thing using C#, but I just can't figure out how to do that.

I already tried different code in C# that uses connection strings like this:

```
string projectId = "data-warehous-511371";
string instanceId = "test-sql";
string databaseName = "mytestdb";
string username = "sqlserver";
string password = "password"; 

string connectionString =
    $"Server=projects/{projectId}/instances/{instanceId}/databases/{databaseName}" +
    $";User Id={username};Password={password};" +
    "Authentication=ServiceAccountCredential";

SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

connection.Open();
```

But no approach I tried seemed to get me anything near finding a solution. It seems that C# is not the language to use with Google Cloud.

I'd be glad for any help you can give me, that could help me connecting my C# application to my Google Cloud hosted SQL Server 2022 Express database.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you must connect over public IP, then using the [Cloud SQL Auth Proxy](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-proxy) is your best option. Granted, you'll have to run it as a separate process next to your app, but the Proxy will expose a secure tunnel to your database.

So you'd do this:

```
./cloud-sql-proxy <INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>
# starts localhost listener on 1433
```

And then in your app, you'd just connect to `localhost:1433`.

If you're connecting over private IP, it's equally feasible to connect directly and avoid using the Proxy.

Comment: If the software should be used outside of the private network, I have to do it over public IP and Proxy right? Can the proxy be build in the software or does everybody who uses the software have to install the proxy on their PC as well? I am a complete novice in Google Cloud

Comment: Yes-- if you aren't running the software in the private network, public IP is a reasonable alternative. The Proxy binary runs as a separate process. So you'd run it on the same machine as your application.

Comment: Note that you can also consider using "Authorized Networks" where you allowlist the CIDR range of the machine that accesses the database. This approach allows you to also connect directly.